# How can I rename files in multiple subfolders based on the name of the subfolder using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, rename

I am trying rename a large number of pdf files that are split between multiple subfolders. The structure would something like C:\State\County\Operator\file.pdf
I have been able to rename the pdfs in individual Operator folders using the following code:

```
for count, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_name = "Operator" + str(count)

    new_name = f'{f_name}{f_ext}'
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

which gives file names in the format "Operator0.pdf", "Operator1.pdf", etc., which is the format I want.
However this requires me to copy and paste the new Operator folder into the code each time and I am hoping to streamline it better.

Is there a way I can write the code where I can just loop through the operator subfolders within the County folder and get a similar result to the code I already have?

I have tried several solutions from other threads, but cant get the results I want or dont know how to apply them to my situation. If there is already an existing thread that solves this, a link would be appreciated. I am still pretty new and am trying to figure things out.

Comment: `os.scandir` provides information about all items contained in a directory. You can filter for subdirectories then.

Comment: Which of these names are variable? I assume "State" and "County" are stand-ins for specific states and counties. But what about "Operator"? Is it literally "Operator", or is that a standin for potentially many operators in the county folders? Is this structure exactly 3 folders deep and you want to process just pdfs in that third folder?

Comment: It would be great to have some sample paths and what you want the final to look like.

Comment: Operator is just a stand-in. I have multiple operators within each county.  A sample path would be "C:\TX\Goliad\Shell" and the pdfs would be Shell0, Shell1, etc.

Comment: The answer by Genchev below is almost exactly what I need, I just need the pdfs to be renamed with the individual operator names.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `os.walk()` function? It works by generating the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up.

Maybe this can help you.

```
import os

root_dir = "C:\\State\\County"  # replace with your directory

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
    for count, f in enumerate(filenames):
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if f_ext == '.pdf':  # only rename PDF files
            new_name = f'Operator{count}{f_ext}'
            old_file = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            new_file = os.path.join(dirpath, new_name)
            os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Just be sure to replace the directory with your own. Also, be careful when running this, because it will rename all PDF files in the directory.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need. The only thing is that I have multiple "Operator" folders with different names, each with various numbers of pdf files. How should I change it so the pdfs within each Operator folder take the name of that folder?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Genchev was 95% what I needed. I added "parent_folder_name" to the "new_name" variable and it gives me what I need. Thanks for the help.

```
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
        for count, f in enumerate(filenames):
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            if f_ext == '.pdf':
                    parent_folder_name = os.path.basename(root)
                    new_name = f'{parent_folder_name}{count}{f_ext}'
                    old_file = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                    new_file = os.path.join(dirpath, new_name)
                    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```